# What resources are using an Elastic IP?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, elastic-ip

Looking at my billing details in the AWS console, I discovered that most of my monthly expenses (this is my dev account, so I don't use a lot) are due to an Elastic IP address in a region without any running EC2 instances.

**Would there be any resources that are using this EIP other than EC2 instances in the same region? If so, how can I trace that?**

Comment: Elastic IP addresses are charged at 0.5c/hr. So, worst case it should be under $4/month per unused EIP.

Comment: You can submit a ticket and ask AWS guys to remove that IP from your account.

Answer (score 0):

EIPs can only be associated with EC2 instance and network interfaces, but [you are also charged for EIPs not associated with anything](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/on-demand/#Elastic_IP_Addresses). You should be able to see in the EC2 -> Elastic IPs section what EIPs you have lying around, and from there you can delete them.

Comment: There is also a charge for Elastic IP addresses attached to instances that are Stopped. Basically, there is no charge if they are "in use". Secondary EIPs on an instance are _always_ charged.